# R Unicode for space

Tags: r, unicode, space

all. I am a beginner of R. 
I try to read a text file (csv) into R. The correct version should be "Our mission, which has...", however, after I loaded the file, I got "Our U+00A0 mission, which has..."

Here is how I load my code:

```
mission = read.csv(file.choose(),header=T, stringsAsFactors=F, encoding="UTF-8")
```

I know  is unicode for space, but can anyone let me know how can my Rstudio show a space instead of 
Can anyone please help?

Comment: `R`s representation of that is `\U00A0`, so either you change your csv file, or use `gsub` to replace `U+00A0` with `\U00A0`.